# Find a line ends up with '-' in regular expression python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to locate the lines which end up with '-' in a text file. I used the following expression but not working. I am not familiar with regex. Can someone help me? thank you!

```
if re.match(r'[.*+]+\-+[\r\n]', lines[i]):
    return i
```

Comment: Why would you need regex for something that simple?

Comment: I just want to practice to use regex and learn it.

Answer (score 5):

`re.match` will match the string only if it finds a match from the beginning of the string. If you really want to use `re.match`, you can use the following regular expression

```
if re.match(r'.*-$', lines[i].rstrip("\n")):
    return i
```

But you don't need regular expression at all for this task, you can do something like this

```
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.rstrip("\n")[-1] == "-":
       return i
```

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you! My mind just got stucked. I will use this, but how about the regular expression?

Comment: `.strip()` will also remove trailing spaces, so it will match lines like `"- "`. Whether or not this is an issue depends on the data, but it doesn't technically solve the questioner's problem. There will also be an exception raised if the line is empty.

Comment: You should also use `.endswith("-")` to avoid the problem of empty lines raising an exception.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really seem like a task that you'd need regex for, but the expression below will do it.

```
.*-$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

`.*` will match any character "zero or more" times with `$` specifying that `-` must be immediately followed by the end of the string.

**EDIT**

If you set the flag to set `^` and `$` to match newlines, it will do just that. I wouldn't recommend matching newline characters explicitly ('\r\n' in your case) as these are dependant on your environment.

By defualt, `.*` will not match newlines.

Comment: End or string? Shouldn't it be the end of line?

Comment: If you set the flag to set `^` and `$` to match newlines, it will do just that. I wouldn't recommend matching newline characters explicitly, as these can vary based on OS.

Answer (score 0):

I think re.search should be more simple

```
if re.search(r'-$', lines[i]):
    return i
```